# update screen is unexpectedly closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk

I'm updating my app programmatically on Android 5.1, SDK 22.

Here is my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".AppContext"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_small"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".KioskService" android:exported="false"/>

    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
    </provider>

    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".content.UpdateAlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Here is how i launch the update

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It brings me the system update dialog. On press install it begins the update, progress bar starting to move, but then dialog is automatically going down like finished activity, returning me to Android desktop.

When i try to click the app icon, it returns me "App isn't installed". After some seconds when update process is finished in the background i assume, app can be opened and works as expected.

How to prevent this unexpected close of the update dialog? I want to display the progress to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Flag change resolved it

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```